# vBulletin redirect after login

Tags: vbulletin

Facts:
- main site on www.DOMAIN.com
- vBulletin installed on forum.DOMAIN.com
- vBulletin authentication integrated in main site (no problems here)

Question:
How can I redirect user to some URL from the www subdomain upon authentication?

Extra info:
I am already using the extra "url" field in the login form, but it only works
for URLs relative to forum root (i.e. I can set it to "forum.php?...", but if
I set it to "http://some_domain/" it is ignored and user is redirected to forum 
home after authentication).

Thanks,
Puiu

Comment: Found the answer myself: just created a plugin attached to "login_redirect" hook and modify the $vbulletin->url value to the desired URL ("url" field in POST in my case), don't forget to escape/check the value in the "url" field you get from the login form ;)

Comment: i wish you could answer your question in details so that others can get benefit as well.